# Finding the $r$ and $s$ value that makes the identity correct

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Decide *r* and *s* so that the following identity is correct:
>
> $$x^2 + 8x + r = (x+s)^2$$

I simplified it down to this:

$$6x + r = s^2 +s$$

But for here (or somewhere else), how do I find the/a value of $r$ and $s$, respectively, that works? Also, is it only one value that works for $s$ and $r$ (again, respectively), or can multiple values work, and I just need to decide which I want to use?

**EDIT:**

Apparently, I simplified it incorrectly, which may have increased my confusion as well. I don't see how I simplified it incorrectly, so here is my simplification calculation:

$$x^2 + 8x + r = (x+s)^2$$

$$x^2 + 8x+r = x(x+s) + s(x+s)$$

$$x^2 + 8x+r = x^2 + s^2 + 2xs$$

$$8x + r = s^2 + 2xs$$

$$6x +r = s^2 + s$$

Comment: Do you know how to [complete the square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square#General_description)?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Haven't heard of that so no

Comment: $x^2+8x+r=x^2+2sx+s^2$ for all $x$ means $2s=8$ and $r=s^2$

Comment: Simplification is not correct

Comment: @Asher2211 as in, simplification is not the way to go, or that my simplification was incorrect?

Comment: its is $2xs $ instead of $s$

Comment: the last step of your simplification looks wrong;  $8x+r=s^2+2xs\implies 6x+r=s^2+2xs-2x=s^2+2x(s-1)$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I removed $2x$ from the $8x$ and left the $s$. Is this not possible? **EDIT:** I see now how it is wrong. The $2x$ is tied up with the $s$ and cannot just be subtracted away like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$x^2+8x+r=x^2+2sx+s^2$ for all $x$ means $2s=8$ and $r=s^2$.

Can you find $s$ and $r$ from here?

**ADDENDUM in response to question edit:**

The last step of your simplification was wrong.

$8x+r=s^2+2xs\implies 6x+r=s^2+2xs-2x=s^2+2x(s-1)$, not $6x+r=s^2+s$

Comment: Yeah I can find them, but I don't see how one can deduce from the above equation that s = 4 and r = 16. How do you find that out?

Comment: Try $x=0$ to get $r=s^2$, and $x=1$ to get $8=2s$

Comment: Both sides of the equation are equal for all values of $x$ so the coefficient of $x$ on both sides of the equation should be the same and the constant term on both sides should be the same.

Comment: I got it now. The tip about setting x = 0 knocked me over the edge of understanding and also the fact about this working with every x-value. The x is variable, but s and r aren't and I forgot about that, thinking x was another constant. Thanks!